# How can I pass optional arguments to a plumber function without overriding the defaults specified by another function?

Tags: r, plumber

I'm new to the plumber package, and I'm trying to figure out how to make a function available, `fun_2`, through an api that can take optional arguments. The optional arguments have their default values specified in a function, `fun_1`, from an R package. How can I accomplish this without having to override the defaults specified in `fun_1`?

I tried the naive approach of just listing the arguments in both function calls with no default values specified in `fun_2`. But that generated a missing argument error.

I also tried specifying defaults in `fun_2`. This worked, but isn't ideal. I don't want to override the defaults specified in `fun_1` in case those change in the future. I want the function called from the api to always have the same results as would be generated by a direct call to `fun_1`.

## fun_1 (in an R package)

```r
fun_1 <- function(x, y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c("d", "e", "f"){
  ...
}
```

## Naive Approach

```r
#* @post /myapi
  fun_2 <- function(x, y, z){
    fun_1(x, y, z)
}
```

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/myapi?x=0.001"
```

```
"error":["500 - Internal server error"],"message":["Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): argument \"y\" is missing, with no default\n"]
```

## This Works But Would Potentially Override fun_1 Default Values

```r
#* @post /myapi
  fun_2 <- function(x, y = c("a", "b", "c"), z = c("d", "e", "f"){
    fun_1(x, y, z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an approach that worked pretty well. I listed all of the `fun_1` arguments in `fun_2`, and set the default values for the optional arguments `y` and `z` equal to `NULL`. Then, I put all of the arguments in a list, dropped the arguments that were null from the list, and then passed the list of the remaining arguments to `fun_1` using the `do.call` function.

```r
#* @post /myapi
fun_2 <- function(x, y = NULL, z = NULL){
  params <- list(x = x, y = y, z = z)
  params <- params[!sapply(params, is.null)]
  result <- do.call(fun_1, params)
  result
}
```